# Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Tags: node.js, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I cannot invoke the method due to the error that appears in the figure. I have no idea how to solve it, do you have any suggestions?

Function that invokes smart contract method in NodeJS is:

```
async function callSmartContractMethod(functionName, arguments, contractAddress) {


    smartContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(contractJson).abi, contractAddress, {
        from: "0x8882528C7104e146E0500203C353C09922575385",
        gasPrice: '1000000'
    });

    log.yellow(`Calling smart contract function: ${functionName} with arguments: ${arguments} smart contract address is: ${contractAddress}`);
    log.yellow.underline('Please wait...');
    return smartContractInstance.methods[functionName].apply(this, arguments).send({from: '0x8882528C7104e146E0500203C353C09922575385'})
        .then((receipt) => {
            log.green(`Transaction of ${functionName} done with success`);
            return receipt;
        }).catch( (error) => {
            log.red.underline(error);
        });
}
```

The method of the smart contract invoked (Solidity) is:

```
    function printOrderReceived(bytes32 _gcodeHash) public {
        require(msg.sender == printer);
        gcodeHashReceived = _gcodeHash;
        b_printOrderReceived = true;
        getCurrentState();
    }
```

Part of the dependencies of the package.json file is:

```
"truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.3",
"truffle-hdwallet-provider-privkey": "^1.0.3",
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.48"
```

[image]

Comment: My guess would be that the address you're sending the transaction from is not the address in the `printer` state variable. You could confirm that by removing the `require` statement and seeing if things work then.

Comment: I thought that 1000000 is usually the value for `gas` and not for `gasPrice`